# Comparar informações iguais de períodos diferentes da mesma tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Senhores, preciso comparar dois períodos de informações iguais, saber quem permaneceu e quem saiu de um mês para o outro.
Ex:

```
-- Nesta Query estou buscando somente dados de novembro
SELECT *
FROM HIST
WHERE DS_PRODUTO like '%Fla%' 
AND ST_CONTA_VALIDA = 's' 
AND ST_CARTAO_VALIDO <> 'n' 
AND DT_MOVIMENTO >= '2022-11-30'
```

-- Nesta Query estou buscando somente dados de outubro

```
SELECT *
FROM HIST
WHERE DS_PRODUTO like '%Fla%' 
AND ST_CONTA_VALIDA = 's' 
AND ST_CARTAO_VALIDO <> 'n' 
AND DT_MOVIMENTO >= '2022-10-30'
```

Eu gostaria de comparar as informações de outubro com as informações de novembro, identificar quem não está mais e quem permanece de um mês para o outro.
Utilizo SQL Server

Comment: Tente LEAD e LAG ..... https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9127/sql-server-window-functions-lead-and-lag/

Answer (score -2):

Tenta utilizar NOT IN ou MINUS

```
SELECT *
FROM HIST
WHERE DS_PRODUTO like '%Fla%' 
AND ST_CONTA_VALIDA = 's' 
AND ST_CARTAO_VALIDO <> 'n' 
AND DT_MOVIMENTO >= '2022-11-30'
AND **CPF** NOT IN (
SELECT *
FROM HIST
WHERE DS_PRODUTO like '%Fla%' 
AND ST_CONTA_VALIDA = 's' 
AND ST_CARTAO_VALIDO <> 'n' 
AND DT_MOVIMENTO >= '2022-10-30')
```

ASSIM VOCÊ SELECIONA QUEM ESTÁ NO PRIMEIRO PERÍODO QUE NÃO ESTÁ NO SEGUNDO.